# Missing coordinates when dividing image into grid

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to partition a set of provided coordinates into several buckets in Python 3 with numpy. I have a grid of buckets. See below:

```
def partition(image, num_tiles):
    """Divide an image into a (num_tiles x num_tiles) grid and return the 
    partitioned input."""

    # The object to return. Ignore - I am just trying to test 'draw' works currently.
    partitioned_image = np.empty((num_tiles, num_tiles), dtype=object)

    draw = []

    # The input array contains coordinates of the form [xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax]. 
    # This is because these are coordinates for bounding boxes around biological cells. 
    # When I say 'point(s)', I refer to a [xMn, xMx, yMn, yMx] array(s).
    xMin = image[:,0]
    xMax = image[:,1]
    yMin = image[:,2]
    yMax = image[:,3]

    # The base to start searching from (not 0,0). 
    x_base = min(xMin)
    y_base = min(yMin)

    # max(?Max) - min(?Min) defines the entire range for the variable. Divide this 
    # range by the number of tiles, which is the number of ticks of the grid. 
    # E.g. range is 100, want a 10x10 grid, so we step along in steps of 10.
    x_step = (max(xMax) - min(xMin)) // num_tiles
    y_step = (max(yMax) - min(yMin)) // num_tiles


    for i in range(num_tiles):
        for j in range(num_tiles):
            # Define the bottom-left point of the region of interest (a tile)
            x_left = x_base + x_step * i
            y_low = y_base + y_step * j
            # Define the upper-right point of the region of interest
            x_right = x_base + x_step * (i + 1)
            y_high = y_base + y_step * (j + 1)

            # Every point in image that is within the region gets added to the
            # draw list. Remember, each point is of the form [xMn, xMx, yMn, yMx]
            result = ((yMin >= y_low) & (yMax < y_high) &
                  (xMin >= x_left) & (xMax < x_right)).nonzero()[0]

            for coordinates in image[result]:
                draw.append(coordinates)

            # I would want to add the actual points to my partitioned_input array
            # here, in the corresponding tile. The above code for draw is *JUST TESTING*.

    # Convert draw list to numpy array and check to see we got all the points.
    draw = np.asarray(draw)
    print(draw.shape == image.shape)  # We do not. This is annoying.

    # Below is the code for plotting. I just take the average of 
    # the xMin/yMin and xMax/yMax values for this.

    draw_xAvg = np.mean(np.array([draw[:,0], draw[:,1]]), axis=0)
    draw_yAvg = np.mean(np.array([draw[:,2], draw[:,3]]), axis=0)

    image_xAvg = np.mean(np.array([image[:,0], image[:,1]]), axis=0)
    image_yAvg = np.mean(np.array([image[:,2], image[:,3]]), axis=0)    

    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30, 10))

    ax1.set_title('Test', fontsize=30)
    ax1.scatter(draw_xAvg, draw_yAvg, s=0.1, c='b')

    ax2.set_title('Image', fontsize=30)
    ax2.scatter(image_xAvg, image_yAvg, s=0.1, c='r')

    ax3.set_title('Overlay (Image)', fontsize=30)
    ax3.scatter(image_xAvg, image_yAvg, s=0.1, c='r')
    ax3.scatter(draw_xAvg, draw_yAvg, s=0.1, c='b')

    # Would return this once I partitioned the input correctly.
    # The idea is to have a list per tile of all the points found in that tile.
    # All I am doing is checking that I get the right number of points in total.
    return partitioned_image
```

Calling code:

```
partitioned_cells = partition(cells, 20)
```

As you can see I step along the input in steps proportionate to the size of the input. This should be completely fine and I do get the vast majority of points so clearly the code is not completely wrong and my logic is fine. However, I expect perfect overlap in the third figure below:

[image: grid]

If you look closely at the righthand figure you can see a distinct grid-like red coming up which the blue is not overlapping, particularly on the right of that figure - the sizes of the resulting numpy arrays (12948 v 13804) also confirm there is a mismatch, with the red outnumbering the blue. I am missing some coordinates in my partitioning.

I have no idea why this is - even when my boundaries are inclusive (`>=` or `<=`) they still do not get all of the points. I don't understand why. Can someone explain or have a guess as to why this might be?

Comment: Can you show how you run the function? It looks like you might not be accounting for remainders when you do integer division.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just use `partitioned_image = partition(image, 20)`. I did wonder about remainders, although given that my upper corresponds to the (i + 1) step ahead I fail to see how this would screw it up.

Comment: How big is the input image?

Comment: Can you add a step-by-step description in your question of what you think your code is doing? I have so many questions at this point, that I think it would be easier for you to just describe your function step-by-step. For example, what is the purpose of `partitioned_image`? What are you expecting `xMin`, etc to do? Why is there no return value shown?

Comment: Will comment the code, hang on a jiffy

Comment: Take your time.